# 3D reconstruction using visualSFM for mac

Tags: c++, git, macos

I am trying to get visualSfm to work on my mac. The link I am following is this: 
https://gist.github.com/patriciogonzalezvivo/0cc2d0fb6e9af9040eff

```
git clone git@github.com:tangrams/VisualSFM_OS_X.git
cd VisualSFM_OS_X
./vsfm_os_x_installer.sh
```

The git clone doesn't work. I think that repository doesn't exist anymore.

The script written by [Dan Monaghan](https://github.com/luckybulldozer/VisualSFM_OS_X_Installer) to compile visualsfm on mac gives this error:

```
Zip file is present, so just unzipping, removing old dir to install so we don't have any conflicts
Archive:  VisualSFM_osx_64bit.zip
   creating: vsfm/
   creating: vsfm/bin/
   creating: vsfm/build/
   creating: vsfm/lib/
  inflating: vsfm/lib/blas.a         
  inflating: vsfm/lib/lapack.a       
  inflating: vsfm/lib/libf2c.a       
  inflating: vsfm/lib/libjpeg.a      
  inflating: vsfm/lib/VisualSFM.a    
  inflating: vsfm/makefile           
  inflating: vsfm/README             
Changing VSFM GCC to Brews gcc-4.8
Changing /usr/x11/lib to OS X default /opt/x11/lib
About to make...
mkdir -p build
mkdir -p bin 
cd build; ar -x ../lib/VisualSFM.a; cd ..;
g++-4.8 -w -o bin/VisualSFM build/*.* -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/X11/lib -pthread -lGL -lGLU -lX11 -ldl -L/usr/local/Cellar/gtk+/2.24.28_2/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/pango/1.38.0/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/atk/2.18.0/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.14.2_1/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/gdk-pixbuf/2.32.1/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.46.0/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -lgtk-quartz-2.0 -lgdk-quartz-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl  lib/lapack.a lib/blas.a lib/libf2c.a lib/libjpeg.a 

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

  "_gdk_x11_drawable_get_xdisplay", referenced from:
      RegisterWin::CreatePaintWnd()       in RegisterGUI.o
  "_gdk_x11_drawable_get_xid", referenced from:
      RegisterWin::CreatePaintWnd()       in RegisterGUI.o
  "_gdk_x11_window_get_drawable_impl", referenced from:
      RegisterWin::CreatePaintWnd()       in RegisterGUI.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

make: *** [VisualSFM] Error 1
VSFM application failed to build, halting.
```

Anybody has any luck with this? Is there any other place where I can find software that does 3D reconstruction for me on mac.

Comment: I am using OS X 10.10.3. I tried to look for an answer here: https://github.com/luckybulldozer/VisualSFM_OS_X_Installer/issues/7 
but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully installed and used VisualSfM on my mac, following Dan Monaghan installation guide. I simply downloaded the zip file.